# Update the same object in an array of object based on Matching key Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This question might be silly but still, I have an array like below.

```
[{"QId":"2030","answer":"~4591^Pain"},
 {"QId":"2030","answer":"~4592^Bad Breath"},
 {"QId":"2153","answer":"~5106^2ede"}, 
 {"QId":"2152","answer":"~5102^24fgf"}, 
 {"QId":"2154","answer":"~5109^No"},
 {"QId":"2152","answer":"~5109^New Answer"}]
```

I want to merge the answer keys of matching QId keys. I want to achieve below output.

```
Output:
[{"QId":"2030","answer":"~4591^Pain~4592^Bad Breath"},
 {"QId":"2153","answer":"~5106^2ede"}, 
 {"QId":"2152","answer":"~5102^24fgf~5109^New Answer"}, 
 {"QId":"2154","answer":"~5109^No"}]
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```js
var AnswersOfQuestions = [{"QId":"2030","answer":"~4591^Pain"},
     {"QId":"2030","answer":"~4592^Bad Breath"},
     {"QId":"2153","answer":"~5106^2ede"}, 
     {"QId":"2152","answer":"~5102^24fgf"}, 
     {"QId":"2154","answer":"~5109^No"},
     {"QId":"2152","answer":"~5109^New Answer"}];

var output = [];

AnswersOfQuestions.forEach(function(val, index) {
  var filteredArray = AnswersOfQuestions.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.QId === val.QId;
  });

  var tempString = "";

  var x = 0;
  for (; x < filteredArray.length; x++) {
    tempString = tempString + filteredArray[x].answer;
  }
  output.push({
    "QId": filteredArray[0].QId,
    "answer": tempString
  });

  tempString = null;
  x = null;

  console.log('output: ' + JSON.stringify(output));
});
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service, show us what you have tried and tell us what about it isn't working

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.  You could start by looping through the array and checking if the QID matches another element in the array. If it does take the answer element of the array and merge them into the output array.

Answer (score 0):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array into an object (`r`) with the `QId` of each object as the key. If an object's `QId` is already found in `r`, add the current answer to it. If not use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) (or [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)) to clone it, and set it as the value of it's `QId`. Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to convert `r` back to array:

```js
const data = [{"QId":"2030","answer":"~4591^Pain"},{"QId":"2030","answer":"~4592^Bad Breath"},{"QId":"2153","answer":"~5106^2ede"},{"QId":"2152","answer":"~5102^24fgf"},{"QId":"2154","answer":"~5109^No"},{"QId":"2152","answer":"~5109^New Answer"}];
 
const result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
  if(o.QId in r) r[o.QId].answer += o.answer;
  else r[o.QId] = { ...o };

  return r;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` with `Object.values()`. Group your object based on `QId`, concat `answer` for repeating `QId` in an object. Then get all the values from this object.

```js
const data = [{"QId":"2030","answer":"~4591^Pain"},{"QId":"2030","answer":"~4592^Bad Breath"}, {"QId":"2153","answer":"~5106^2ede"}, {"QId":"2152","answer":"~5102^24fgf"}, {"QId":"2154","answer":"~5109^No"}, {"QId":"2152","answer":"~5109^New Answer"}],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,{QId, answer}) => {
      r[QId] = (r[QId] || {QId, answer : ''});
      r[QId].answer += answer;
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that creates a `Map`, keyed by `QId`, and then pushes the corresponding answers in it, to finally spit out the result:

```js
const data = [{"QId":"2030","answer":"~4591^Pain"},{"QId":"2030","answer":"~4592^Bad Breath"},{"QId":"2153","answer":"~5106^2ede"},{"QId":"2152","answer":"~5102^24fgf"},{"QId":"2154","answer":"~5109^No"},{"QId":"2152","answer":"~5109^New Answer"}];

const map = new Map(data.map(o => [o.QId, []]));
data.forEach(o => map.get(o.QId).push(o.answer));
const result = Array.from(map, ([QId, v]) => ({ QId, answer: v.join("") }));

console.log(result);
```